# Where does javascript submit() function submit to?

Tags: javascript, forms

I heard about the `.submit()` function in Javascript and even found some articles about it, like [this one](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml)

My question however is, where does this function "submit" to? I don't see an address or an email mentioned anywhere. All that is mentioned, is that you include a call to the function.

Comment: executes before submitting to your form's action attribute!

Comment: It will submit your data to any page you want it to. Where you can place validations on data or do whatever data manipulations you want.

Comment: So what's the difference between that and a submit button?

Comment: You can prevent submit, make validation than call it. If you have only button and HTML4 you can’t validate fields.